# JS/JQuery: Call parents function if child.html() is changed to ""

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent-child

In my *parent.htm* there's a dropdown list, which is filled dynamically from the database using a JQuery function `updateMyList()` in *parent.js*.

If the user wants to add another option to the list, the form *child.htm* is loaded inside `<div id="overlay">` of the *parent.htm*. To insert new data an AJAX request is called from *child.js*, which is included in *child.htm.*

If the request was successful, *child.htm* is unloaded via `$("#overlay").html("")` from *child.js*. When this happens, i'd like to call parent.js's `updateMyList()`, but i can't find a way to trigger it.

Using `opener` from inside child.js didn't work (TypeError: opener is null) and i can't find a way to tell if `$("#overlay").html()` has been changed back to "".

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Sorry if this is a double post, i'm running out of ideas for search terms...

edit: here's a simplified code:

```
parent.htm:

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="parent.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#new-option').click(function(){
        $("#overlay").load("child.htm");
    });     
  });
  </script>
</head>


parent.js:

$(document).ready(function(){

   function updateMyList(){
     //send AJAX and write options
   });

   // and do much more...
});


child.htm:

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/child.js"></script>
</head>


child.js:

$(document).ready(function(){

  // do more stuff

  $('#save-option').click(function(){
     $.post("./inc/savenewoption.php", {
       //save user entries
     }, function(data){
            alert(data);
     })

     .done(function() {
            updateMyList(); // <- this won't work
            $("#overlay").html("");                 
     });
  });
});
```

Comment: you should provide a jsfiddle, and the code

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask

Comment: Since it is all in the same page, where you call `$("#overlay").html("")`, just call `updateMyList()`

Comment: @ mplungjan: tried it, but this gives a "ReferenceError: updateMyList is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because `updateMyList()` is inside a different function (one of your `$(document).ready()` ones). In my experience the only reason you put code into a `$(document).ready()` function is because Javascript can fire before the document has completely loaded.  Trying to fire Javascript on elements before they are in the document will cause errors.

The `updateMyList()` function doesn't fire until the ajax request is complete, so it should be safe to have it located outside `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: Thanks, updateMyList() is working now. But as soon as child.htm is unloaded, one of the jQuery.fn.extend functions in parent.js isn't working anymore (TypeError: $(...).writeOptions is not a function). Relocated it outside of document.ready too, but that didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not familiar with extend functions, sorry.